# Google Sheets - Sorting values using an array of index

Tags: google-sheets

let me explain with an example

I have a column with values like "50, 30, 10, 40, 20" and another one with values like "1, 3, 2, 4, 5". I would like to sort the first set of values using the other set as indexes. So, the result should be a column with:

50, 10, 30, 40, 20

What should the formula be to create this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX(SORT(A1:B, 2, 1), , 1)
```

[image]

---

[image]

.

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you tell me how to solve the same problem if I have those values as rows instead of columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select A where A is not null order by B asc", 0)
```

[image]